# include_str! set "string literal" path

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have to ship a `json` and a `toml` file inside of my Rust binary. It is a standalone app and people don't want to pass in config files at run-time.

**`include_str!`** does what I want.  I can write:

```
static SETTINGS_FILE_STR: &str = include_str!(r"../my_config/settings.toml");
```

Is there a better way to write the file path than `r"../my_config/settings.toml"`?

I can't seem to construct a `string literal` from anything inside of `use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};` or `env`.  I wondered if I could read something out of the `cargo.toml` file. No luck.

I always hit:

```
error: argument must be a string literal
  --> src/main.rs:23:42
   |
23 | static SETTINGS_STR: &str = include_str!(FANCY_PATH_TO_TOML_FILE);
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can't do the following, as `String` is not a ***string literal***:

```
fn get_config_path() -> String  {
    let root_dir = project_root::get_project_root().with_context(|| format!("Failed to get project root directory"))?;
    const path: PathBuf = root_dir.join("my_config/settings.toml");
    path.to_string()
}
```

If this was C / Objective-C, I could use a constructor or Class functions to achieve what I wanted.   As you may have guessed, I am new to Rust.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`include_str!` is a macro and as such executed at compile time. Because the compiler can't yet know what will be the content of the `String` or some static variable at runtime, you can't use `include_str!` with a `String` or a static variable.

However, there is a workaround for referencing files relative to your crate root: You can combine [`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) and [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html) with [the environment variable `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) (set by Cargo at compile time) to do what you want. Both macros emit string literals, so `include_str!` is happy with them.

This outputs the content of `my_config/settings.toml` inside your crate root:

```rust
static SETTINGS_STR: &str = include_str!(concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/my_config/settings.toml"));

fn main() {
    println!("The config: {}", SETTINGS_STR);
}
```

Comment: I would also note here that if you need to include_str! some dynamic Rust, that can also be possible with build scripts: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html . It can be used to generate a file into the out directory that can then be included with include_str, which will happen after the build script executes.

Answer (score 0):

If the file names are to be enumerated dynamically (e.g. contain all files in a directory) then [Elias Holzmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68865971/1644618)'s method will not work either.

In such a case, I would Zip the directory, include it as `include_bytes!` and then read it as zip file to enumerate its contents and use them.

A sample use case would be to include a dist directory of a ReactJS or Vue APP in a webview rust application as a desktop app. Sample code in github will follow as an edit.